# What are the more formal words for "clerk"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request

As title, what are the more formal words for "clerk", who deal with the paper works.
Administrative jobs, managers, secretaries, people standing behind the counters taking your forms...

Edit:
It should be a serious formal word to express that this person is specialized or interested in dealing with PAPERWORKS, DOCUMENTS, and so on.

Finally:
I must have some sort of delusion. I found that the word/phrase I was looking for is simply ***Clerical workers***.

---

*Note: While Matt has given the "correct" answer, the findings from J.R. are also quite mentionable. I'm sorry that my "accepted answer" could only go to one of you. Also thank you Sean despite got a little off.*

Comment: Bureaucrat? Agent? Clerical officer?

Comment: Administration staff, perhaps.

Comment: Kind of. I'm looking for the words to summarize the idea. Honestly I've seen the word once but I can't remember it.

Comment: *Clerk* is sufficiently formal for a job title.

Comment: I agree with Kit.  *Clerk* is a perfectly formal title. http://clerkofcourt.maricopa.gov/

Comment: The informal words are things like: bean counter, pencil pusher,etc.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it asks for a more "formal" term, despite the fact that there's nothing "informal" about the word ***clerk***.

Comment: There is nothing informal to the word ***clerk*** indeed. I am just looking for a more formal writing word for it. The word I've seen feels a little ancient, but I'm not sure at all. I would also keep trying to find out, when I found it I would answer my own question.

Comment: @pioneerlike: That simply doesn't make sense to me. Since *clerk* is ***not*** "informal", it's pretty meaningless to ask for a "more formal" alternative. I would seriously advise against J.R.'s *scribe, scrivener, notary* - such alternatives aren't so much "formal" as "archaic".

Comment: @FumbleFingers "Notary" isn't archaic, at least in the US. However, the term is much more specific than "clerk". A "Notary Public" or just "notary" is someone who is legally authorized to witness signatures. The notary will countersign the document, and then punch a (typically county) seal through the signatures and dates, so they can't easily be altered.  Getting this done to a document is called having it "notarized".

Comment: @BobRodes: Yeah, I know ***notary*** has always been a more important/significant/necessary word in the US (mainly because of the potentially-significant *distances* involved). But [overall prevalence is declining](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=notary+public&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnotary%20public%3B%2Cc0). It was only ever really an American usage anyway, and I don't really see it suddenly coming back into fashion. I bet there are more "official" texts where it's been *removed* than where it's been *added* to new "legalese"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with one of the following:

> An ***[administrative] assistant*** (*esp*. with junior staff)
>
> ***[Office] support staff*** (slightly more broad than just clerks, but often used synonymously)
>
> A ***bureaucrat*** (*esp.* with mildly negative connotations)
>
> ***Clerical staff***

But there's nothing wrong with using the word *clerk*, it's not informal, and it's a widely understood word that would be readily understood by your readers.

Answer (score 0):

In government offices, these are commonly known as either administrative officers or administrative assistants, depending on their levels of responsibility.

Answer (score 0):

Clerk is an overused term. A person who keys in data is a data entry keyer or a data entry operator or computer operator not a data entry clerk. A receptionist could be an information specialist not  reception clerk or an administrative support clerk. A typist is a typist or keyer not a clerk typist or typist clerk. A word processing operator is just that or maybe a text editor but not a word processing clerk. Office workers are office assistants, office specialists, staff support specialists or administrative support specialists. Well you wouldn't want to use the last one because you would come up with an embarrassing acronym.

Answer (score -1):

The word that springs to mind is an [official](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/official) (n: 1):  One who holds an office or position

The words from the [thesaurus](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/official#Thesaurus) entry may also give you the word you are looking for.

Comment: I've never heard a secretary, clerk, or administrative assistant ever referred to as an "official," either informally, or in job title.

Comment: I gave you +1 back.  It seems a bit harsh to downvote a wrong answer when you did your research and got misled by a bad dictionary definition.  (I don't suppose the downvoters did their due diligence by reading it?  No, probably not.)  The actual definition is "One who holds an office or position, especially one who acts in a subordinate capacity for an institution such as a corporation or governmental agency."  While people who hold offices are generally officials, people who hold positions are most often not.  I hold a position (my job), but I'm not by any means an official.

Comment: @J.R.  (and in contrast to @BobRodes) You have never heard a clerk referred to as an official, because (apart from a few archaic cases) an 'official' normally refers to someone on the level _above_ this.

Answer (score -1):

I can't tell if this is the word you are looking for or not, but when I checked *clerk* in a thesaurus, it listed ***scrivener***, with the label `historical`.

It's defined by NOAD as:

> **scrivener** (*noun*) `historical`
>   a clerk, scribe, or notary.

Wikipedia mentions:

> A **scribe** is a person who writes books or documents by hand as a profession and helps the city keep track of its records. The work could involve copying books, or secretarial and administrative duties, such as taking of dictation and the keeping of business, judicial and, historical records for kings, nobles, temples, and cities. Later the profession developed into public servants, journalists, accountants, typists, and lawyers.

Either *scrivener* or *scribe* would fall into the category mentioned in your comment, in that the words have an "ancient" feel to them.

Comment: 'Historical' is a warning that this is no longer current/normal usage.

Comment: @MikeB - Absolutely true. The main reason I've even bothered to include it here was because the OP remarked in a comment: _The word I've seen feels a little ancient, but I'm not sure_.